# Can magento 2.1.0 GA smoothly upgrade to 2.1.1?

Tags: upgrade

Magento 2.1.1 is just released and I'd like to upgrade my 2.1.0 GA to 2.1.1. Since I already have data and modules in 2.1.0 so that I'd like to know if anyone have successfully upgrade to 2.1.1 from 2.1.0 GA? If so, could you please provide steps of your upgrade procedure? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, You can upgrade from magento 2.1.0 to 2.1.1 successfully without any issue.

I have just recently upgrade from 2.1.0 to 2.1.1 with many order,customer,products and custom module.

Not any problem after upgrade to latest version.

you have to just upgrade using below method,

Using Command line method is best fit to upgrade,

Go to **`composer.json`** file at root,

> `Change "version": "2.1.0", replace with "version": "2.1.1",`

and another changes are inside **require**,

```
 "magento/product-community-edition": "2.1.0" replace with
 "magento/product-community-edition": "2.1.1"
```

Now go to cmd,

run command from root,

**`composer update`**

All process are starting for upgrade.
After some times it will upgrade to latest version of your project.

```
Basically all core files are updated automatically which have required to upgrade inside  magento.
```

After upgrade complete,

Run command,

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade

Remove Var folder from root.

Run deploy command,

> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Run indexing command,

> php bin/magento indexer:reindex

**`First try with in your local server to see working or not.`**
Clear browser cache and check your changes.

Comment: If you have useful, please feel free to close this questions using accepting answer

Comment: Rakesh's solution is working good for me except for the following two points:
1. https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/6426
2. when run setup:di:compile, there is an error like ScopeInterface is already included in the Context (which is working fine previously). But simply remove this from DI and call $this->_scopeConfig seem perfectly legal. and therefore it works fine.